# Rails string of array of hashes with keys - convert to array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this string which I pass with an ajax call from an API response (I cannot alter the data before sending to Rails, since it is done with jQuery in the view)

```
str = '{"0"=>{"firstName"=>"Testing", "lastName"=>"It", "email"=>"test@example.com"}, "1"=>{"firstName"=>"Tester", "lastName"=>"You", "email"=>"test2@example.com"}}'
```

I want to parse it into a ruby array of hashes.

The most logical parsing with JSON fails:

```
JSON.parse(str)
```

> JSON::ParserError (765: unexpected token at '{"0"=>{"firstName"=>"Testing", "lastName"=>"It", "email"=>"testing@example.com"}, "1"=>{"firstName"=>"Tester", "lastName"=>"You", "email"=>"test2@example.com"}}')

Any ideas how to parse this **elegantly** without gsub or splits. Perhaps convert the string somehow to Ruby array of hashes format somehow?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON would have colons (:) where this has the "=>" operator. Either figure out how to get proper JSON from the API or gsub the "=>" for ":"

Comment: It is not clear what array you want. The string you have, which is not a valid JSON, could be interpreted as Ruby, in which case it would be a hash, not an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2):

Since that's a ruby hash, you can use eval

```
hash = eval(str)
```

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod, I didn't know about eval. It works as well. So both the answers are true in this case, however, I believe Hayden's comment is the most effective suggesting to avoid sending the data in the wrong format in the first place. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hayden for pointing this out! Indeed I was passing an invalid JSON because I was passing the object and not the JSON. Solved by passing the array object from the view with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If the question has turned out to be an XY-question, and you have solved it in another way, write that perhaps as a comment to your question, or addition to your question, not as an independent answer here.